Keydb server not accepting connections after a few hours
I have a set of applications connecting to a Keydb server. If i restart my services multiple times the keydb server becomes unresponsive. It stops accepting further connections, but keydb will still be running though. Once it becomes unresponsive it cant accept connections even from within the keydb machine. This makes me believe that i can eliminate any proxy/connectivity issues.
Therefore my suspicions were primarily based on the keydb machine's resource utilization and the number of active connections the keydb deals with.
The resource utilizations are minimal with a very low memory/CPU usage when the keydb is unresponsive. There is enough disk space in the machine.
The connection count also remains pretty much the same when the connectivity is successfull and unsuccessfull. Sometimes during the unresponsive state it has much lesser active connections compared to when the connections are successfull.
The keydb server logs stop at the moment the connections are blocked, no logs after that. I have enabled debug logs also to track down the issue.
The server machine logs also shows no error. It shows keydb logs normally and suddenly starts showing connection refused logs.
Any help on what might be the issue or what i am missing here would be great.
